# Async call causing EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, concurrency

The app I'm working on is using a function that is working fine but blocks the main thread. I am attempting to add a loading spinner using SVProgressHUD and that requires I call my function asynchronously in order to display the spinner. As soon as I call the function asynchronously however the app crashes with `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0` The only change I have made to the function is to invoke the `popViewControllerAnimated` lines on the main thread. Why is running this code on a new thread causing it to crash and how can I fix it?

Calling code:

```
-(void) _doSaveDataPoint {
    
    
    [SVProgressHUD show];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        
        
        [self _saveDataPoint];
        
        
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        });
    });

    
}
```

_saveDataPoint function. popViewController called on main thread near the end of this code:

```
    -(void) _saveDataPoint {
    
    NSString *errorMsg = nil;
        if ([[myLegend type] isEqualToString:@"PIN"]) {
            if ([myNodes count]==0) {
                errorMsg = @"Please make sure you have added one point on to the map to continue.";
            }
        }
        else if ([[myLegend type] isEqualToString:@"POLYGON"]) {
            if ([myNodes count]<3) {
                errorMsg = @"Please make sure you have at least 3 points set before continuing.";
            }
        }
        else {
            if ([myNodes count]<2) {
                errorMsg = @"Please make sure you have at least 2 points set before continuing.";
            }
        }
        
        if (errorMsg !=nil) {

            UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Not enough points"
                                                  message:errorMsg
                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                                       actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                           // Just dismiss
                                       }];
            [alertController addAction:okAction];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
            });


            return;
        }
        
      
            
            ClientLegendDataPointBounds *bounds = [[ClientLegendDataPointBounds alloc] init];
            
            int count = 0;
            GeoPoint *first = nil;
            NSMutableDictionary *attr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            for (_EditAnnotation *anno in myNodes) {
                GeoPoint *point = [[GeoPoint alloc] initWithLatitude:[anno coordinate].latitude andLongitude:[anno coordinate].longitude];
                [bounds expand:point];
                if (count==0) {
                    first = point;
                    count++;
                    continue;
                }
                NSString *xKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x%d",count-1];
                 NSNumber *xCoord = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[point latitude ]];
                 NSString *yKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"y%d",count-1];
                 NSNumber *yCoord = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[point longitude]];
                 [attr setObject:xCoord forKey:xKey];
                 [attr setObject:yCoord forKey:yKey];
                
                
                count++;
            }
            
            if (count>0) {
                NSString *pointCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count-1];
                [attr setObject:pointCount forKey:@"pointCount"];
                
            }
        
        
            [self _setBarThemeDefault];
              if (myDataPoint==nil) {
                  myDataPoint = [myLegend addDataPoint:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[DateTime currentTimeInMillis]] title:@"" description:@"" latitude:[first latitude] longitude:[first longitude] attributes:attr type:[myLegend type] bounds:bounds];
                  
                  
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                      [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                  });
                  
                      
                  [myHandler newItemCreated:myDataPoint];
              } else {
                  [myDataPoint setAttributes:attr];
                  [myDataPoint setBounds:bounds];
                  [myDataPoint setLatitude:[first latitude]];
                  [myDataPoint setLongitude:[first longitude]];
                  [myDataPoint setModified:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[DateTime currentTimeInMillis]]];
                  [myDataPoint update];
                  
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                      [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                  });
                  
                  [myHandler itemUpdated:myDataPoint];
                  
              }
        [self _finishSurveyLog:[SurveyLogItem ACT_SAVE_SPATIAL_CONST]];
        [self _saveUserLocation];
        
    
}
```

Comment: No error message in console when this happens?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are modifying the viewcontroller hierarchy and then trying to hide the progressHUD. Having a "save" function dismiss a viewcontroller is a bit of a code smell. It should only be concerned with saving. Dismissing the view controller should be done by the caller, probably based on some completion handler or result returned from the save function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the plugin but could it be that the plugin itselfs dispatches the ui stuff to the main queue? So you don't have to dispatch the call to the main queue by yourself. Take a look at the source code:
[SVProgressHUD.m](https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD/blob/master/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.m)

Comment: I don't think SVProgressHUD does this unfortunately. If I call the function as it was without specifically calling popViewController on the main thread the app will crash complaining that I need to call that line on the main thread.

Comment: Hmm this looks like a weird problem. Isn't "[SVProgressHUD dismiss];" called immediately after  _doSaveDataPoint is invoked? It should be executed after "_saveDataPoint" is finished right? Is there some callback mechanism needed?